# Prevent custom user role to add new pages

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

How can I prevent my custom user role to not be able to add new pages.

I have this array of capabilities for my user role:

```
    $args = array(
        'delete_others_pages' => false,
        'delete_others_posts' => false,
        'delete_pages' => false,
        'delete_posts' => true,
        'delete_private_pages' => false,
        'delete_private_posts' => true,
        'delete_published_pages' => false,
        'delete_published_posts' => true,
        'edit_others_pages' => true,
        'edit_others_posts' => true,
        'edit_pages' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
        'edit_private_pages' => true,
        'edit_private_posts' => true,
        'edit_published_pages' => true,
        'edit_published_posts' => true,
        'manage_categories' => true,
        'manage_links' => true,
        'moderate_comments' => true,
        'publish_pages' => false,
        'publish_posts' => true,
        'create_pages' => false, //THIS SETTING DOES NOT WORK / EXISTS
        'read' => true,
        'read_private_pages' => true,
        'read_private_posts' => true,
        'upload_files' => true,
    }
```

With these settings my user role can still "Add new page" but the page will then be submitted for "review" by an administrator.

My user should be able to "edit existing pages" but may not "add new" or "delete" any pages.

For "posts" the user should be able to "add new", "update" and "delete" any posts (full control). And the same for "Custom Post Types".

Best Regards

Shane Madsen

Answer (score 2):

Post types in WordPress have a list of capabilities that govern permissions surrounding them. These are:

```
edit_post
read_post
delete_post
edit_posts
edit_others_posts
publish_posts
read_private_posts
read
delete_posts
delete_private_posts
delete_published_posts
delete_others_posts
edit_private_posts
edit_published_posts
create_posts
```

Internally each post type matches these to the *actual* capabilities that can be given in WordPress. Most of the time these have the exact same name. So the `edit_posts` capability of the `post` post type is `edit_posts`, while the `edit_posts` capability for the `page` post type is `edit_pages`.

The one exception to this is `create_posts`. This is the post type capability that WordPress checks to decide whether a user can create a new post of that type. It checks this:

```
if ( current_user_can( get_post_type_object( 'page' )->cap->create_posts ) ) {}
```

Unlike the other capabilities, for posts and pages `create_posts` is actually mapped to `edit_posts` and `edit_pages` respectively, not `create_posts` or `create_pages`, which don't exist.

So if you printed `get_post_type_object( 'page' )->cap->create_posts` you'd see that the value is `edit_pages`, and users with that capability can see the Add New button. Because this is `edit_pages` and not `publish_pages`, it allows users to create new pages and posts even if they can't publish them, they'll just be put into pending review, which is the behaviour you want to prevent.

For custom post types you can control this behaviour by setting `create_posts` in the `capabilities` argument to something else:

```
register_post_type(
    'my_custom_type',
    [
        'capabilities' => [
            'create_posts' => 'manage_options',
        ],
    ]
);
```

For that custom post types, only users with `manage_options` will be able to add new posts.

For the built in post types you can use the `register_post_type_args` filter to set this capability however you'd like for the default post types:

```
function wpse_342743_create_page_capability( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'page' === $post_type ) {
        $args['capabilities'] = [ 
            'create_posts' => 'manage_options',
        ];
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse_342743_create_page_capability', 10, 2 );
```

With that code only users with `manage_options` will be able to create new pages, but they will still be able to update them without review if they otherwise have `edit_pages` and `publish_pages`. You can change this capability to be `delete_pages` so that only users who can delete pages can create them, or you could pass your own custom capability that you'll give to users to give them the ability to create pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking you time answering my question! I will look into it and get back to you when I manage to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

> this parameter should work for this

```
'publish_pages' => false,
```

Comment: But they won't be able to update existing pages without putting them back into pending review.

Comment: In my array I already have set publish_pages to false. The user is then able to "add new page" that on submit will be sent to review. I need to get rid of the "Add new" button (not with css or js) so the user doesn't have this option.

Comment: @JacobPeattie You are right. When publish_pages is false pages need to be reviewed again when updated. Hmm.